# Powershell command-line parameters not populating

Tags: powershell, parameters

I can't seem to get a command-line parameter given when calling a Powershell script to actually populate the parameter variables in the script.

I am running a simple Powershell script, and passing in a command-line parameter. All I want to do is display the parameter. But the parameter does not appear to be getting populated.

I have tried several variations that I've found online, some using args[0], but I can't seem to get it. This should be a straightforward thing! What am I missing?

Here is the .ps1 script I am running, called MyScript1.ps1:

```
param(
[String]$p1
)
Write-Host "Param p1 = <$p1>"
```

and I call it like this from a command prompt:

```
H:\> MyScript.ps1 -p1 myvalue
```

I would expect this to display this:

> Param p1 = <myvalue>

but it displays this:

> Param p1 = <>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get `Param p1 = <myvalue>` from `.\MyScript.ps1 -p1 myvalue` (powershell prompt)  as well as from `powershell -noprofile -command .\MyScript.ps1 -p1 myvalue` (Windows `cmd` prompt).

Comment: Also unable to replicate.

Comment: I know this is a dumb comment, but your post references `MyScript1.ps1` as having the script contents. Yet your example calls `MyScript.ps1`. Is it possible there are actually two scripts and you are calling the wrong one?

Comment: @AdminOfThings, good spot, but that was just a typo. I have only 1 script.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out, thanks to the comment by JosejZ.

When I call my script via a Windows command prompt like this:

```
C:\>MyScript.ps1 -p1 myvalue
```

then p1 is not populated. However, if I call the script via Powershell like this:

```
C:\>powershell -file ./MyScript.ps1 -p1 myvalue
```

then p1 *is* populated, and I get the expected output.

I did not realise that calling a script from a Windows command prompt results in different behaviour than when calling a script from the Powershell command prompt.